# How can I dynamically modify an eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a simply Eloquent query that returns data to a grid.  The grid (Nayjest) is very particular about the data that it can use, so I am stuck using the "newQuery()" functionality.

```
$query = (new Position)
->newQuery()
->select('*')
->where('positions.Active', '=', 'A');
```

The query is driving my apps report functions, so each report may have up to 10 different WHERE parameters.

```
$query = (new Position)
->newQuery()
->select('*')
->where('positions.company','like','Z%')
->wherebetween('positions.posno',['1000','3500'])
->where('positions.Active', '=', 'A');
```

The report query parameters are all data driven, and I can easily parse out each WHERE command, but how can I dynamically piece the WHEREs into the overall query so that it works properly?

Does Eloquent have any sort of "Macro Substitution" functionality?  That's how I've accomplished this in the past (this is my first go with Eloquent).  How can I do something like this?-->

```
$Where1="->wherebetween('positions.posno',['1000','3500'])"

$query = (new Position)
    ->newQuery()
    ->select('*')
    &Where1
    &Where2
    &Where3
    &Where4
     ;
```

If I use the traditional Eloquent syntax, piecing together wheres and finishing up with a "Get()" then I can run the query, but the grid won't accept it as a data source.  What's the difference between the results from newQuery() vs. Get()?

Comment: The difference between `newQuery()` vs `get()` is that one returns a query object, the other returns a collection of items fetched by the query. You can't do "something like this" because that's not how PHP works. You're manipulating an object, not building a string.

Comment: You're not really explaining what kind of problem you're facing here, or what kind of answer you're expecting from us. Can you clarify what you're trying to do, and what challenges you're having doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I'm too new to Laravel/Eloquent to have asked a clear question, but still your answers got me pointed in the right direction and I came up with a solution.  The root of my confusion was that I didn't realize that I could break the 6 lines of the "newQuery()" directive into individual lines.  Once I figured that out it came pretty easily:

```
  $query = (new Position)
    ->newQuery()
    ->select('*');
    
    if (!empty($query1)){
      $query = $query->where('positions.Active', '=', 'A');
    };

    if (!empty($query2)){
      $query = $query->where('positions.company', 'like', 'S%');
    };
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

```php
$query = (new Position)
    ->newQuery()
    ->select('*')
    ->where(function($query){
        $query->where('positions.company','like','Z%')
            ->wherebetween('positions.posno',['1000','3500'])
            ->where('positions.Active', '=', 'A');
    });
```

All where's nested inside a wrapping where will result in a SQL query with &where for all the wrapped wheres